# Cause of this kernel panic IOVideoPocketCamDevice::terminate

Tags: macos, imac, kernel-panic

When I started my iMac 27-inch, it shows the message "your computer has been restarted because of an error".

I searched on the internet and Apple's site said that it might be a software issue so I reinstalled macOS, but even after that the same error is showing after boot up within ~20seconds

Could anyone help by reading the following log report, whether it's software or hardware issue? and which apps should I delete in safe mode? Also when I boot up in safe mode the screen would transition slowly in horizontal lines(is this normal?)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems /Library/Extensions/IOVideoPocketCam.kext hasn't been updated for High Sierra. Remove this kext and reboot the machine.

1. Boot into Safe Mode (hold ⇧ whilst turning Mac on until Apple logo) and log in as usual.
   Safe Mode disables all third-party extensions so this problematic kext won't be loaded.
2. Open Finder, press ⇧⌘G and enter `/Library/Extensions`.
3. Find IOVideoPocketCam.kext and delete the file (move to Trash).
4. Reboot as normal.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, iam a novice , could you please tell me how should I remove .kext file, considering the fact that I have very less time after boot? Should I go into safe mode? Then what steps should I follow?

Comment: @JM97 I've added instructions, see edit

Comment: THANK YOU very much, it solved the problem and saved a lot of time, I was afraid if I have to pack this machine and go to apple store for repair.